# convert a cell to an upper triangular matrix

Tags: matlab

I have a cell C where size(C) = 1x28. Each cell contains a 10x10 matrix. I would like to reshape C to form an upper triangular array M with size(M) = 8x8. Each cell of M above the diagonal should contain the original 10x10 matrix. Any suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: The cell C can be generated by using the following C = cell(1,28);

for i = 1:28

    C{i} = num2cell(rand(10,10));
end

Comment: well its solved! I first generated the row and column index for an upper triangular matrix. [v2,v1] = find(triu(ones(8),1)); Then I created an empty cell as M = cell(8,8); then I populated the matrix  for z = 1:28
    M{v2(z),v1(z)} = C{z}; end

Answer (score 0):

If your struct contains only *numeric* values you can use `cell2mat`:

```
C = num2cell(rand(8)); % generate random cell array
M = cell2mat(C); % convert cell to matrix
MU = triu(M,1); % get the upper triangular matrix
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional [context](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) regarding _how_ and/or _why_ it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now! Please [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/43488114/edit) your answer to add an explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Comment: thanks for the comment, added the limitation of cell of numeric values